# Suppressing Output of Paramiko SSHClient Class

Tags: python, paramiko

When I call the connect function of the Paramiko `SSHClient` class, it outputs some log data about establishing the connection, which I would like to suppress.

Is there a way to do this either through Paramiko itself, or Python in general?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Paramiko doesn't output anything by default. You probably have a call to the logging module, setting a loglevel that's inherited when paramiko sets up it's own logging.

If you want to get at the paramiko logger to override the settings:

```
logger = paramiko.util.logging.getLogger()
```

There's also a convenience function to log everything to a file:

```
paramiko.util.log_to_file('filename.log')
```

Comment: You can filter out DEBUG and INFO messages with: logger.setLevel(logging.WARN)

Comment: When I tried paramiko.util.log_to_file('filename.log'), file is empty even for pass and failure cases. Anyone know anything else need to be setup ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what Paramiko is, and there must be a log level setting for sure, but if you are desperate and looking for a temporary solution and if your app is single threaded

```
import sys
dev_null = sys.stdout = sys.stderr = open('/dev/null', 'w')
try:
.
. connect()
.
finally:
  dev_null.close()
```

you can use StringIO for output also, if you are on an OS not have a '/dev/null'